# How do I setup rsync and any other scripts to mimic a minimal viable replica of DropBox?

Tags: backup, sync, rsync, dropbox

The tools I use to mimic the service are not as important as creating a reliable replacement in case something happens to the DropBox company (price flux, acquisition, etc)

My original question was focused on using couchDB replication, but this isn't a requirement just a potential path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Project lipsync](https://github.com/philcryer/lipsync)  uses [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd)  to watch a folder for changes, and then kicks off a command, which is rsync by default. For examples, see "[Lsyncd (Live Syncing Daemon) synchronizes local directories with a remote targets](https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer3/)"

So, you could set it up to issue the curl command to kick off CouchDB replication, instead of rsync, to have lysncd call that instead - I haven't done it, but it should work. Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: I believe my original question was too restrictive, but you're answer was very helpful. Marked it correct and will dig into your suggested links.