# Real-Time Multi-Client Synchronization with Conflict Management

Tags: linux, windows, sync, nas

I need to setup a synchronization between my Computers with a NAS in the local network. The setup is somewhat complicated, though, so I am assuming there is not an off-the-shelf product that does what I need.

#### Details:

Devices I use:

- Desktop PC, dual-boot Windows 10 / Arch Linux
- Laptop (Arch Linux)
- NAS (self-build, FreeNAS running on it)

I've used `rsync` so far to backup to the NAS (one-way, my dual-boot setup uses the same storage for both OS).

The problem is, I would like to get the Laptop in the sync.
Therefore I need to do some kind of two-way sync.

Problems that arise here:

1. I often save files only seconds before the shutdown, so I need to monitor file changes instead of running a sync tool periodically

   - I cannot sync my laptop outside of the local network (and in the local network, I use the desktop PC most of the times); the local (updated) version could be quite out of date and give some conflicts.
2. I do want to use the local network only (probably the existing network share of the NAS), not an ownCloud or something similar, because we have quite limited bandwidth where I live and I have some rather huge files to keep synced.

#### My ideas

I found this question: [How do I setup rsync and any other scripts to mimic a minimal viable replica of DropBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/298837/), and looked into a solution using [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) (Live Syncing Daemon), which synchronizes local directories with remote targets. This could solve problem #1, but I still need to be prepared for conflicts. Furthermore, I could not find any docs about lsyncd on Windows, so I assume it won't work there.

I also looked at the potential to incorporate [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) into a solution; it seems to do two-way syncs. Maybe I could use it together with lsyncd.
I'm not sure about the conflict handling, though. I found a hint that with `-batch`, conflicts are just skipped. But how do I handle conflicted files in the long term (I want to sync them, after all)?

So my question is, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Please be aware that the question is not only about a software recommendation, but rather about ideas how to solve the problem (possibly with unix tools).
Thank you for the On Topic link, actually I was looking for something like this when I asked the question as I was not sure whether to put this here, but I could not find this one.
I do not think this belongs to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com either, as I don't expect there even is a ready-to-use tool as stated in their [OnTopic](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
I'll try to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @DavidPostill As stated in [OnTopic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), the question is now about "personal and home computer networking" and no more "asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation". I think this fits [these suggestions](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) quite well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your NAS - I'm pretty fond of [BitTorrent sync](https://www.resilio.com/) for this. It runs on most systems (including raspberry pis and mips systems) with support from quite a few consumer NAS systems (like my seagate). You just pick a folder to share, generate a key, and use the key to set up the share on each system you want it on. Its smart enough to detect you're on a LAN, works outside of it. The free version works well enough for my needs - I mainly use it to sync downloads from a system I keep on all the time and backups of many small files that I add to infrequently.

It'll do what you need - one way or two way sync,  using the lan if needed. It deals with conflict by keeping a copy of deleted files, (which I turn off for my use cases) and generally runs well enough that I hardly notice it.

Comment: I'll have a look into it! Maybe better to use this solution instead of patching sth together by myself. The advantage of the scripting approach is (for me), that the SMB-share is automatically backed up (it's a zfs). OTOH the disadvantage is that my script might break with updates for unison...

Comment: I'll accept your solution, as most ppl reading this will probably be better of with bitorrent sync.

Answer (score 2):

So, my self-developed solution requires a bit more scripting than [the one of Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/a/1146041/287528). I used [`unison`](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) for the sync-part and [`zenity`](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) to warn for conflicts.

### Scripts

The bash script (put this into your startup-applications):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$(arp | grep MAC_ADDRESS_OF_NAS)" ]; then
    zenity --warning --text="NAS not found. Aborting."
fi;
unison sync -batch=true -repeat=watch |& while read -r line; do
    if test -n "$(echo $line | grep skipped:)"; then
        zenity --warning --text="$line"; 
    fi;
done
```

The unison configuration (put this as `sync.prf` into `~/.unison/`):

```
root=/home/my-username/the-data-i-want-to-backup/
root=/mnt/NAS/some/sub/path/

# follow all symlinks
follow = Path *

# automatically do everything (if there are no conflicts)
auto = true

# for some reason unison fails if I sync the permissions
perms = 0
dontchmod = true
```

### Detailed explanation (and troubleshooting for derivates)

1. First I check, if the NAS is found in the local network.
   If its MAC-address does not appear in the `arp` output, I assume I don't need to sync.
   This needs probably some further tweaking as I rarely turn my laptop off completely, so the script won't be started when I connect to the network.
   Maybe I'll add a cron job or some kind of "on-network-connect"
2. [`zenity`](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) can be used to create graphical dialogs from a bash script.
   You probably need to install it.
   Basic usage is pretty straight forward.
3. `unison sync` starts the synchronization.
   It looks for a configuration profile called `~/.unison/sync.prf`.
   I could substitute `sync` by something else (both in the filename and the command).
4. To skip conflicted files, I specify `-batch=true`.
   I don't do this in the config file because I want to run `unison sync` manually if a conflict happens.
5. I don't need a third party tool to watch for changes: `-repeat=watch` does exactly what I want.
   *Sidenote: actually it starts a full resync on any change, so it could do better, but that's ok for me.*
6. The output of the `unison`-command is a bit strange, took some time to get this working:

   - If there's a conflict, the output contains `skipped: FILENAME`
   - That seems to happen on STDERR rather than on STDOUT, so I need to pipe with `|&`
   - For some reason I could not figure out it did not work with a simple `grep` for me. I tried something like `unison sync ... |& grep "skipped:" | xargs zenity --text="{}"`, but that would not execute until unison finally finished (it worked fine without `-repeat=`, and it worked fine without the `grep`)
7. For above reasons I sticked with a while loop to read the input and use the grep only on each line itself
8. In the unison profile, notice that I used absolute paths. For some reason it did not work with `~/my/folder`

### Additional notes

- I'm someone who tends to over-engineer. I setup a script generating me the unison-profile. In case you're interested:

  ```sh
  #!/bin/bash

  HOME_DIR=$(cd ~; pwd)

  REPO_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")"

  UNISON_PRF=$HOME_DIR/.unison/sync.prf

  # write sync script
  read -e -p "Local sync dir: [like ~/Data] " LOCAL_SYNC_DIR
  # make path absolute:
  LOCAL_SYNC_DIR="${LOCAL_SYNC_DIR/#\~/$HOME_DIR}"
  read -e -p "Remote sync dir: [like /mnt/NAS/Data/] " REMOTE_SYNC_DIR
  REMOTE_SYNC_DIR="${REMOTE_SYNC_DIR/#\~/$HOME_DIR}"

  rm "$UNISON_PRF"
  echo "root=$LOCAL_SYNC_DIR" > "$UNISON_PRF"
  echo "root=$REMOTE_SYNC_DIR" >> "$UNISON_PRF"
  cat "$REPO_DIR/sync.prf" >> "$UNISON_PRF"

  # user info
  echo "IMPORTANT: You need to put $REPO_DIR/unison/sync.sh to your startup applications for this to work properly!"
  ```